# Calculus question involving summation and multiplication series

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I was unable to solve this question properly, but as it was multiple choice, I scaled down the upper limit to $3$ and got an answer matching with the pattern. I am still unable to solve it.

I have tried to approach the question by trying to form a general term for integrand and then try to proceed using summation series.

---

$$
  \int_0^1
  \left( {} \sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac{x^2}{x^3 + k^3} \right)
  \left( {} \prod_{k=1}^{2014} {} (x^3 + k^3) \right)
  \mathrm{d}x
  =
  \frac{1}{\lambda}
  \left[ {} \prod_{k=1}^{2014} {} (1 + k^3) - \mu^3 \right]
$$
Find $\lambda, \mu$.

---

Comment: What is the derivative of $f(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{2014} (x^3+k^3)$ with respect to $x$? Hint: it might be helpful to first find $\frac d{dx}(\log f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ and then derive $f'(x)$ from that.

Comment: Are you sure that the first summation starts at $k=0$ and not $k=1$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, I made an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you the general calculation and you can put in your number into any arbitrary arithmetic program. Swapping $2014$ for the general $N$, we have, following the first commenter's suggestion

$$\frac{d}{dx}\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} \left( x^{3} + k^{3}\right) = 3\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+k^{3}}\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} \left( x^{3} + k^{3}\right)$$

This result is basically a fancy application of the ordinary product rule from calculus 1. If you want me to expand it, please ask, but my inclination is not to clutter this demonstration with material which is not very enlightening.

We therefore have

$$\int_0^1
  \left( {} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{x^2}{x^3 + k^3} \right)
  \left( {} \prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (x^3 + k^3) \right)
  \mathrm{d}x$$

Substitute

$$u = \prod_{k=1}^{N} {} \left(x^3 + k^3\right)$$

then

$$\mathrm{d}u = 3\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{x^{2}}{x^{3}+k^{3}}\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} \left( x^{3} + k^{3}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

and we now have

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\mathrm{d}u$$

where I used a little poor form and did not recalculate the limits of integration.

$$\left.\frac{1}{3}u\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}$$
$$\left.\frac{1}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (x^3 + k^3)\right)\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1^3 + k^3)\right)
- \frac{1}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (k^3)\right)$$

You now set this equal to the RHS of the problem

$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3)\right)
- \frac{1}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (k^3)\right) = 
\frac{1}{\lambda}\left[ {} \prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3) - \mu^3 \right]$$

After rearranging I get

$$ \frac{\lambda}{3}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3)
- \left(N!\right)^{3}\right) =
\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3) - \mu^3$$

For you, $N = 2014$. Please let me know if there is a problem, but after setting N = 2014, you should have the relation between $\lambda$ and $\mu$. I don't see how there can be a unique answer. The "most obvious" answer seems to be to set $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=(N!)^3$, but I would think the relation has a family of answers.

Note, the commenter said to use $\frac{d}{du}\ln(u)=\frac{du}{dx}$, but I don't see how to do that. All I see is a $\mathrm{d}u$ form. Let me know.

Edit:

I just looked at it and this obviously cleans up to

$$\lambda = 3\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3) - \mu^3}{\prod_{k=1}^{N} {} (1 + k^3) - \left(N!\right)^{3}}$$

which defines $\lambda$ as a function of $\mu$.

Comment: Don't you think that after substitution the expression should be just $\int_{x=0}^{x=1} du$ instead of  $\int_{x=0}^{x=1} udu$

Comment: I read it as the integral of the Sum times the Product. The Sum is basically the derivative of the Product. So, if the Product is u, the Sum is du (it is actually 1/3 du). Thus, I get an integral of udu.

Comment: The integral is Sum times Product and no the Sum isn't the derivative of the Product. Sum times Product is the derivative of the Product, hence it should be 1/3 times an integral of du.

Comment: Yup, got it, thanks.

Comment: Additionally, the easy answer falls right out now, although I still don't think it is unique. I updated it to include the $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=(N!)^{3}$ answer.